# Article visibility in customer portal and partner portal

Tags: customer-portal, knowledge, partner-portal

I read this while going through Knowledge implementation guide -

> Customer Portal users inherit the role visibility of the manager on
>   the account.

Can anyone please explain this. I don't have any idea about Customer portal and Partner portal.